# What does it mean to pass an array of pointers in C?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, parameter-passing

I am struggling with pointers concept of C, precisely with Array of pointers. See the below program for reference.

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int a1[] = {6,7,8,18,34,67};
int a2[] = {23,56,28,29};
int a3[] = {-12,27,-31};
int *x[] = {a1,a2,a3};

void print (int *a[]){
  printf ("%d",a[0][2]);
  printf ("%d",*a[2]);
  printf ("%d",*++a[0]);
  printf ("%d",*(++a)[0]);
  printf ("%d",a[-1][1]);
 
}

void main (){ 
  print (x);
}
```

what I don't understand is, if we are passing `int *a[]` as an array of pointers, it should be an array after all right ? but I'm being told that here **a** is only a single pointer variable which acts as an alias to **x** but according to the syntax **a** should be an Array, ie. the activation record of `print()` function should contain an array not merely a pointer variable that holds the base address of **x** but that's the whole confusion is it a pointer or an array of pointers, the syntax surely suggests that it should be an array of `int` pointers, I read online but got way more confused, please don't disregard this question by flagging irrelevant.

Comment: Did you read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/), the documentation of your C compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)... to be invoked as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`), and of your debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)...). See also [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) and [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) or some newer C standard

Comment: I don't think I am facing problems with semantics but rather with understanding the concept of array of pointers.

Comment: Are you allowed to use a debugger? And to run your program step by step? And to draw on paper figures (representing pointers by arrows, like in [linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) wikipage?) What will happen to you if you read the [documentation of GDB](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) ? BTW, you could consider installing [Debian](http://debian.org/) on your laptop

Comment: BTW, you could code   `printf ("at line %d, we have %d\n",__LINE__, a[0][2]);` and likewise elsewhere, then recompile and run your program in a debugger

Comment: Did you read the wikipage about [pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming))s? And the one on [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) ? You may want to read some [good operating system textbook](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/). Can you reads books on paper? Are you allowed to use the [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) ? Or [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com)?

Comment: I did now, but it's taking me away from the point,  I'm not concerned about the ourput but about the memory layout of these arrays, as in say, a1,a2,a3 will reside in static memory and will be integer arrays?

Comment: You may want to run `gcc -fverbose-asm  -Wall -Wextra -O2 -S your-prog.c` and look inside the generated assembler code `your-prog.s`, assuming you are allowed to use [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)

Comment: Ok thank you for your time, I will surely debug this with GCC. All I was looking for was the memory layout and variable profiles.

Comment: If you are allowed to use both the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler and the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger, I recommend compiling with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g your-prog.c -o your-binary` then using `gdb your-binary`. But **you need to read the documentation of your compiler and of your debugger.**

Comment: Surely thanks, I will.

Comment: Do you know about how [array pointer decay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay) works?

Comment: @Nate Eldredge Not formally though, I read it online that an array name is converted to a pointer.

Comment: No, array names are not converted to pointers. Names are relevant in source code. Pointers are relevant in your executable. Think of [cross-compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler): names in source code and pointers can be on *different* computers. And you could lose your source code and still keep your executable

Comment: Thank you guys I am starting to get this now, As I realize, I was short on understanding the decay concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two cases where an array "decays" into a pointer to its first item:

- Whenever the array name is used in (most) expressions, or
- When a function parameter is declared with array type.

The reason `int *x[] = {a1,a2,a3};` works is because those 3 arrays "decay" into a pointer to their first element here. Which in all 3 cases is of type `int*`, so it is compatible with the element type of the `x` array.

Then when you define a function such as `void print (int *a[])`, the compiler silently and implicitly "decays" this array declaration into a pointer to the first element. The first element of an `int* []` array is an `int*` and a pointer to one is `int**`. So this function is equivalent to `void print (int** a);`. That's why we can write an empty `[]` here - the compiler doesn't care about the array size since it will replace the array with a pointer anyway.

And that's also why the multiple levels of indirection `a[0][2]` works. This is *not* because `a` is a 2D array - it isn't. But the first `[]` does pointer arithmetic on the `int**` type to get the relevant `int*` element. And the second does pointer arithmetic on that pointer element in turn, to get to the actual `int`.

As for the various lines inside that function, it's some sort of artificial school example meant to teach about operator precedence. Hint: postfix operators usually have the highest precedence.

The line `a[-1][1]` is a bug since it invokes undefined behavior - we shouldn't write programs like that and the reason why is a somewhat advanced topic of it's own. Detailed info here: [Is it undefined behaviour to just make a pointer point outside boundaries of an array without dereferencing it?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/277215)

Comment: what pointer arithmetic does the operator ```[]```do on an address, can you please elaborate more on that?

Comment: @PawanNirpal Like any pointer arithmetic, each index or +1 increases the offset by `sizeof(type)`. So in case you do pointer arithmetic on a `int**` pointer, you'll get chunks of `sizeof(int*)`.

Comment: Yes thank you, that's what I was  expecting wasn't  sure though, now I am, thanks again.